# How to prove that L={w|#a(w)=#b(w)=#c(w)} is not context free using closure

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages

How can I prove that the language `L={w|#a(w)=#b(w)=#c(w)}` is not context free using closure ?

Thanks

**EDIT :**

I know that the language `L1 = {a^i b^i c^i | i>=0}` is not a context free language . 
Now I'm trying to find another language `L2` , where `L2` would be a regular language , in order to make a contradiction , since if `L1` is context free and `L2` is a regular language , then `L1∩L2` is also context free .

Comment: can you show what you have tried please?

Comment: you might want to ask on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ instead if you get no answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in order to get from `L` to `L1`, you need to impose an ordering on the a's, b's and c's. There's a really simple regular language you can intersect with `L` to impose this ordering - can you see what it is?

If you know how to prove that `L3 = { w | #0(w) = #1(w) }` is non-regular using closure properties, the proof of this one is really similar.

Comment: I think you mean to `L = {a*b*c*}` ?